# Questions/Problems Powerschell WinUserLanguageList

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, ui-automation, powershell-5.1

I'm building a code to fix keyboard layout situation on windows 10. With automated solution, I decided to use PowerShell. But the problem is when ever i try to set to set the WinUserLanguageList
it Creates a new Belgium language list out of nowhere. Any idea on to why this?

Code

```
$languageslist = New-WinUserLanguageList -Language en-GB
$languageslist[0].InputMethodTips.Clear()
$languageslist[0].InputMethodTips.Add('0813:00000813')
$languageslist
Set-WinUserLanguageList $languageslist -force
Get-WinUserLanguageList
```

Output

```
LanguageTag     : en-GB
Autonym         : English (United Kingdom)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United Kingdom)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {0813:00000813}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False

LanguageTag     : en-GB
Autonym         : English (United Kingdom)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United Kingdom)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False

LanguageTag     : nl-BE
Autonym         : Nederlands (België)
EnglishName     : Dutch
LocalizedName   : Dutch (Belgium)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {0813:00000813}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

Wanted output

```
LanguageTag     : en-GB
Autonym         : English (United Kingdom)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United Kingdom)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {0813:00000813}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False

LanguageTag     : en-GB
Autonym         : English (United Kingdom)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United Kingdom)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {0813:00000813}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

Answer (score 2):

The input method tips setting you're using assigns the nl-BE language:

> Dutch - Belgium   nl-BE: Belgian (Period) (0813:00000813)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs

The input codes (keyboards) are actually a language:keyboard pair, so the `0813` says nl-BE, while `00000813` is the keyboard you want.

You can just update your inputMethodTips value to use `0809` for en-GB, with the Belgian keyboard like so:

```
$languageslist[0].InputMethodTips.Add('0809:00000813')
```